# Проиндексировать единицы в датафрейме, но не считать нули

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame, в котором записаны нули и единицы,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,0,1,1,1,0,1]})

   A
0  0
1  0
2  1
3  1
4  1
5  0
6  1
```

Необходимо пронумеровать только 1, а 0 оставить без изменения, т.е. должны получить:

```
   A
0  0
1  0
2  1
3  2
4  3
5  0
6  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [186]: df.groupby(df['A'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()).cumsum()
Out[186]:
   A
0  0
1  0
2  1
3  2
4  3
5  0
6  1
```

Пошагово:

разница между текущей и предыдущей строкой:

```
In [2]: df['A'].diff()
Out[2]:
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    1.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
5   -1.0
6    1.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

сравниваем значения из шага `[2]` с `0`:

```
In [3]: df['A'].diff().ne(0)
Out[3]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

кумулятивно суммируем то что получилось на предыдущем шаге `[3]` (в Python - `False == 0`, `True == 1`):

```
In [4]: df['A'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
Out[4]:
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    4
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

дальше группируем по значениям из шага `[4]` и считаем кумулятивную сумму:

```
In [8]: df.groupby(df['A'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()).cumsum()
Out[8]:
   A
0  0
1  0
2  1
3  2
4  3
5  0
6  1
```

Comment: Я понимаю, как создается маска внутри groupby() ( данном случае она выглядит таким образом [1,1,2,2,2,3,4]). А потом groupby() присваивает 0 нечетным значениям, а 1 четным?
Но ведь groupby() по идее должен разбивать на группы не по четности, а по номинальному значению, разве не так?

Comment: @NikIshmametev, добавил пояснения в ответ...